# Custom SVM for cv2.HOGDescriptor.setSVMDetector()

Tags: python, opencv, svm

How to obtain the weights for SVM in OpenCV 2.4.6 for Python 2.7.5?

I need this to calculate the primal form of my `cv2.SVM()` to feed it to a `cv2.HOGDescriptor().setSVMDetector`.

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033363/obtaining-weights-in-cvsvm-the-svm-implementation-of-opencv) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339657/training-custom-svm-to-use-with-hogdescriptor-in-opencv) SOF useful, but it seems like `SVM.decision_func` is protected and I cannot access this variable to obtain the weights.

Are there any other ways to do this in Python+OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Save](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/support_vector_machines.html)** method to save SVM to hard drive.

If you need only weights then I think you need to modify code or look closer at format in which opencv svm saved.

here some info
[OpenCv SVM output file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806448/opencv-svm-output-file-format)

Comment: I think the problem is with `const CvSVMDecisionFunc* df = decision_func;` in the SOF that you shared. `decision_func` is protected and cannot be accessed using Python+OpenCV AFAIK.